# Can't Get the Total Value after using PIVOT in SQL SERVER Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table

Here I have Query for my report and also Execute it successfully but i don't got my answer properly,  **In my answer I want the Total for the Receipt, MRN_P, Issue, Rejection, Transfer_P, and Transfer_M** but instead of i got the null values which is shown in image....Plz Help me at where my Code is Incorrect

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DailyProcessReport] 
AS 
BEGIN


SELECT 
tra_item, 
IsNull(sum([Receipt]),0)as Receipt,
IsNull(sum([MRN_P]), 0)as MRN_P, 
IsNull(sum([Issue]), 0)as Issue, 
IsNull(sum([Rejection]), 0) as Rejection, 
IsNull(sum([Transfer_P]),0)as Transfer_P, 
IsNull(sum([Transfer_M]),0)as Transfer_M, 
[Receipt] + [MRN_P] + [Issue] + [Rejection] + [Transfer_P] + [Transfer_M] as 'Total' 

FROM 
(   
    SELECT tra_item, tra_quantity, tra_type
    FROM
    tra_master 

) as pvt

PIVOT (Sum(tra_quantity) FOR tra_type IN ([Receipt], [MRN_P], [Issue], [Rejection], [Transfer_P], [Transfer_M])) as pvt

Group by tra_item, [Receipt], [MRN_P], [Issue], [Rejection], [Transfer_P], [Transfer_M] 

END
```

and result we got  **Here in Total Column I Want summation of all rows instead of Null**

[image]

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for the `GROUP BY`, nor the second set of `SUM()`s in the outer `SELECT` clause because the `PIVOT` already performed the necessary `SUM()` - why do you have those in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should be sufficient:

```
SELECT 
  tra_item, 
  IsNull([Receipt],0)as Receipt,
  IsNull([MRN_P], 0)as MRN_P, 
  IsNull([Issue], 0)as Issue, 
  IsNull([Rejection], 0) as Rejection, 
  IsNull([Transfer_P],0)as Transfer_P, 
  IsNull([Transfer_M],0)as Transfer_M, 

  IsNull([Receipt],0)+IsNull([MRN_P], 0)+IsNull([Issue], 0)+ 
  IsNull([Rejection], 0)+IsNull([Transfer_P],0)+IsNull([Transfer_M],0) as Total
FROM 
(   
    SELECT tra_item, tra_quantity, tra_type
    FROM
    tra_master 

) as pvt

PIVOT (Sum(tra_quantity) FOR tra_type IN ([Receipt], [MRN_P], [Issue],
       [Rejection], [Transfer_P], [Transfer_M])) as pvt
```

I can't work out what you were trying to do with your `GROUP BY` and the `SUM()` inside of your `ISNULL()`s, since the `PIVOT` already performs a `SUM()` and it is performing an implicit `GROUP BY` on all of the columns not mentioned in the `PIVOT` (here, `tra_item`).

Comment: Thank you very much Damien .....as I am new to this all, 
so, I make this code from the help of Google (With out much Understanding :-) ...)

now i have one another query will you plz help me..??